# iOS/Xcode: Main Thread Checker doesn't seem to be activating, but still a crash due to UI being called on background thread?

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, mapkit

Working on an iOS app with the following crash:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: >' initWithCoder:: MKMapView >must be initialized on the main thread.'

More bizarre seems to be that the call stack indicates this originated from an embed segue in my code (the controller that holds the map).  The map is already visible and interactive, however, so it seems odd that this would be occurring.

> 15  UIKit                               0x00000001071ffc07 __67-
>   [UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate
>   newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 180

I've enabled Main Thread Checker *and* pause on issues in my debug scheme (verified it is set to debug, and verified it operates by intentionally putting in some background thread UI updating code and removing it after Main Thread Checker kicked in).

I would have assumed that Main Thread Checker would have caught whatever it is I'm doing wrong re: the map, and I would have gotten a handy 
"UI API called on a background thread".  However, I get nothing but the crash, so no idea what I would be doing wrong re: threading (I believe all of my UI updates are wrapped in the usual dispatchqueue.main.async, etc.) so that I could fix it.

a) Am I misunderstanding how Main Thread Checker works?

b) Has anyone experienced this issue with Mapkit + embed segues previously?

c) Is there another way to catch what it is I might be doing wrong?

In case it helps, the full stack trace.  Please note that I receive this *after* the tabs and map have already loaded and are present in the UI.

```
2017-12-20 23:04:34.829770-0800 XXXXXX[93019:3557775] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
 Stack:(
    0   Foundation                          0x0000000103a76ec6 _AssertAutolayoutOnAllowedThreadsOnly + 77
    1   Foundation                          0x0000000103880d7a -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 28
    2   UIKit                               0x0000000106ecb5e8 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _resetLayoutEngineHostConstraints] + 75
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001064356c2 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1388
    4   QuartzCore                          0x00000001061a13ee -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 153
    5   QuartzCore                          0x00000001061a54dd _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
    6   QuartzCore                          0x000000010612dded _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 365
    7   QuartzCore                          0x0000000106159704 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 500
    8   QuartzCore                          0x0000000106159d79 _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 213
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b3d539f _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 544
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b3d50d9 _pthread_exit + 152
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b3d365d pthread_attr_getschedpolicy + 0
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b3d307d start_wqthread + 13
)
2017-12-20 23:04:34.850538-0800 XXXXXX[93019:3557775] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '<MKMapView: 0x7f8d30a9b200; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)> initWithCoder:: MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104bf71ab __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103e51f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c6bcb5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   MapKit                              0x0000000102e09546 -[MKMapView initWithCoder:] + 1368
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000106a42a45 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000106a4277a -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001067f0218 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 178
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000106a42a45 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000106a42be3 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1118
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000106a4277a -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001067ef415 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1262
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000106508838 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 383
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000106509164 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000106509495 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000106509cf2 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000106fa0c07 __67-[UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 180
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000106c8bdcb -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 279
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000106c8bc83 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000106c8bf4b -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 157
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000106509685 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 691
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000106509cf2 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000106578094 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 466
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000106577417 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 59
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000106573404 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 410
    24  UIKit                               0x00000001065731d3 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 109
    25  UIKit                               0x00000001064268f0 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 90
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010656d6dc -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 512
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010656e727 -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 211
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010650f59c -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 444
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010650fe31 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 147
    30  UIKit                               0x00000001065517da -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 843
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010655263f -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 841
    32  UIKit                               0x00000001065538c3 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    33  UIKit                               0x00000001067aca49 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
    34  UIKit                               0x00000001064356f5 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1439
    35  QuartzCore                          0x00000001061a13ee -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 153
    36  QuartzCore                          0x00000001061a54dd _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
    37  QuartzCore                          0x000000010612dded _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 365
    38  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106159704 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 500
    39  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106159d79 _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 213
    40  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b3d539f _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 544
    41  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b3d50d9 _pthread_exit + 152
    42  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b3d365d pthread_attr_getschedpolicy + 0
    43  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b3d307d start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker):

> The Main Thread Checker is a standalone tool for Swift and C languages that detects invalid usage of AppKit, UIKit, and other APIs on a background thread.

It's possible that their definition of "other APIs" doesn't include MapKit. I know that MKMapView technically inherits from NSView or UIView depending on the platform, but I would say that it's possible that the Main Thread Checker doesn't catch any warnings or signals outside of UIKit, AppKit, and your app (I don't know this for sure, just a guess).

One common issue is attempting to perform a segue in `viewDidLoad()`, but it doesn't seem like you're doing that.

Are you doing anything that leads to inadvertently triggering a segue on the background thread?

Comment: "Are you doing anything that leads to inadvertently triggering a segue on the background thread?"

Nope.  The "embed segue", so to speak, is set on the Storyboard.  That's the only embed segue that is present.

I never considered the fact that Mapkit isn't part of UIKit though...lol...maybe the answer to my a) is "yes".  =)

Thanks!